# Our first community ad has been launched!

Tags: discussion

[image]

Over on the [ELL post for community ads](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2854/community-promotion-ads-2016), one of Language Learning's own ads (one of my own creation) has exceeded the minimum threshold of positive votes (6) to be displayed on the main site. This actually happened quite a while ago, but I haven't actually regularly monitored the status of our community ads.

According to [this metric](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2854), this ad has pushed a total of 367 clicks to our site, about 2.45 clicks a day since this ad hit the required threshold, so it may have contributed to the influx of new visitors coming to our site.

Just thought I'd let you all know (if you weren't already aware)!

Comment: In spite of those 2.45 - 2.5 clicks per day, we are are at 51 visitors/day, which is on the low end even for LL SE. Hope it will help in the long run.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Is it really that low? If I'm not mistaken, we were at our all time low of ~30 visits a day. That might be a false memory though :). Either way, I do expect we should see an increase in visitors once we repost all of our community ads on the 2017 community ad meta post on various language-related SE sites.

Comment: Since mid October, we've always had between 53 and 64 visitors per day. (I have been monitoring these data.)